# How to make a custom assert that crashes on the custom asserted line without the use of macros in Swift

Tags: swift, macros, assert

I want to create a custom Assert method.

Since there are no macros in swift, I've had to create a function.  Apple says macros are not needed and you can achieve the same thing with a function.

The problem is that my analytics treats all of the crashes as the same crash.  It says that the crash happens in my custom assert method instead of in the file where the crash actually happened.

In objective-C I could create a macro and the macro would just inject the code when compiled so all crashes where treated as their own crash.

How Can I achieve this similar behavior with swift without macros?

This is an example of my current situation

```
func someMethodThatCrashes1() {

   //Should say the the crash happened here in this file
    MGAssert(false, message: "Opps.  There was a crash.")
}

func someMethodThatCrashes2() {

   //Should say that a different crash happened here
    MGAssert(false, message: "Opps.  There was a different crash.")
}

/** Custom Assert function. */
public func MGAssert(_ contition:Bool, message:String) {    
    if contition == false {        
        NSLog("%@", formattedMessage)

        //Crash is actually detected as being here 
        //and treats all crashes as the same crash
        assert(false, formattedMessage
    }
}
```

[Edit]

I don't think this is a duplicate.  Let me elaborate on my question.

I know macros are not possible in swift.  I don't want to create a macro.  I also know that we can use #file, #line, etc to get information about where the code is currently executing.

I'm trying to get my custom assert function to behave the same way as the native assert method.

When the native assert causes a crash, analytics picks up the crash as being on that function.  So every different assert is treated as it's own crash because app things it crashed where the assert() was called.

Unfortunately, when I wrap it in my MGAssert() function, the crash is not detected on the line where my MGAssert() is.  It is still detected on the native assert() function within my MGAssert() function.  Consequently, all of the crashes caused by MGAssert() is detected as the same crash.  It is treated as if the MGAssert() function crashed on the line with the assert().  It treats it as the same crash even if MGAssert() is called from different parts of the application.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: This is pure speculation on my part, but what happens if you decorate MGAssert with `@inline(__always)`?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are `#file` and `#line` now, but the same approach should still work.

Comment: @jlew I tried '@inline(__always)' as per your suggestion and ran some tests but this did not fix the issue.  It still counts the crash as happening on the 'abort()' within the function.  It was a nice try though.

Comment: @MartinR I Edited the question.  The duplicate you linked to does not answer the question.  Can you please reopen it so people can answer.  Thanks.